# Who is this Green Lantern member?

Tags: dc, character-identification, green-lantern, doomsday

While reading [**Final Crisis #5**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Crisis_Vol_1_5), I noticed that one panel shows a Green Lantern who looks remarkably like the villain Doomsday. He has orange skin instead of grey, but otherwise they look fairly identical. Given that Doomsday is a unique creation and not a race of beings... how is this possible? As far as I can tell, he only shows up in that one panel.

**Can someone identify the creature in the panel below, as well as his relationship (if any) with Doomsday?**

[image]

Comment: I see that others have researched a name for the fellow. Still, I have to note that artists love to have fun when faced with the task of doing great crowds of the 3,600 Green Lanterns. When each alien has to be unique, they apparently love to slip in lookalikes and homages to all manner of aliens depicted in other comics.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sounds like Turytt.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turytt

> Turytt is a very tall, well-muscled humanoid alien with red skin, a
> blonde ponytail down the center of his head, and protruding jagged
> horns on his abdomen, arms and head. Other distinguishing features
> include claws on each hand and superhuman strength. Turytt bears a
> vague resemblance to the Superman villain Doomsday.

[image: Turytt]

It's hard to prove a negative, but I can't find any link to Doomsday beyond appearance. [ComicsVine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/turytt/4005-47277/) says:

> Turytt’s home planet has not been revealed, but his resemblance to the monster Doomsday is striking. It is unknown if this resemblance is a mere coincidence, or if there is a connection between Turytt’s species and that of the infant used in the accelerated natural selection experiments conducted to create Doomsday.

Answer (score 7):

Searching up Final Crisis #5, I was sent over to [this wikia page](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Crisis_Vol_1_5), where they name him as [Turytt](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Turytt_(New_Earth)). [His wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turytt) seems to have more information about him than the Wikia one.